# Contrast for hourly counts between 4 groups

Tags: chi-squared-test, biostatistics, medicine

I am studying the incidence of different types of stroke in a hospital. I have the information about the time of arrival of each patient and the type of stroke. I divided the whole day into 6 time slots (00-04, 04-08, 08-12, 12-16, 16-20, 20-00) and counted the number of each type of stroke (ischemic stroke, hemorrhagic stroke, transient stroke and mimic) in each time slot.

I obtained the following table:

| Time slot | Ischemic stroke | Hemorraghic stroke | TIA | Mimic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00-4 | 32 | 5 | 1 | 5 |
| 4-8 | 50 | 18 | 2 | 15 |
| 8-12 | 271 | 58 | 22 | 86 |
| 12-16 | 259 | 32 | 28 | 92 |
| 16-20 | 191 | 32 | 15 | 60 |
| 20-00 | 205 | 49 | 9 | 100 |

The hypothesis I want to test is whether the frequency of each type of stroke is constant over time. I performed a Chi-squared test, obtaining a p value = 0.00175.

However a revisor of a journal says the test is not appropriate to test. He says: "The chi squared test tells you about the correlation of stroke types with each other, but not with the time of day."

As far as I know chi squared test could be appropriate for this data. What do you think?

Do you think I could perform another type of analysis to improve it? (I also have the raw data)